# Translating a grammar file in a hand written parser

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, yacc

I've been trying to write my own compiler for educational purposes and I'm stuck on an issue. I've taken the recursive descent approach with some previous knowledge on lex and yacc/bison.

So far I'm just trying to handle the parsing aspect without regards to the generation of the AST or code generation.

I'm trying to write the expression parsing for this particular grammar file part

```
primary_expression
    : IDENTIFIER
    | CONSTANT
    | STRING_LITERAL
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

postfix_expression
    : primary_expression
    | postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
    | postfix_expression '(' ')'
    | postfix_expression '(' argument_expression_list ')'
    | postfix_expression '.' IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression PTR_OP IDENTIFIER
    | postfix_expression INC_OP
    | postfix_expression DEC_OP
    ;
```

So far I have this code

```
void Parser::primaryExpression()
{
    if (accept(Token::eIdentifier))
    {

    }
    else if (accept(Token::eIntNumber))
    {

    }
    else if (accept('('))
    {
        expression();
        expect(')');
    }
}
void Parser::postfixExpression()
{

}
```

I'm having some problems dealing with the recursiveness of the `postfix_expression` and I don't know how to continue with `postfixExpression` function.

I'm under the impression that for a recursive descent parser, I should probably arrange my grammar in a different way.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See my SO answer on how to write a recursive descent parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left-recursion is difficult to handle in an LL (recursive descent) parser -- you need to recognize at and change it into a loop rather than a recursive call.  In general terms, you want to refactor the left-recursion into

A → α | A β

and then your recusive descent routine becomes

```
parseA() {
    parseAlpha();
    while (lookaheadMatchesBeta())
        parseBeta();
}
```

Note that this requires enough lookahead to distinguish between FIRST(β) and FOLLOW(A), in order to find the end of all the trailing things that can match β

This is the same as the process for eliminating left recursion in an LL grammar -- you are effectively replacing the rule above with

A → α A'
A'→ ε | β A'

and then replacing the tail-recursive call in `parseAPrime` with a loop and inlining it into `parseA`.

Doing that with your grammar and using the accept/expect technique your code above uses, you get something like:

```
void Parser::postfixExpression() {
    primaryExpression();
    while (true) {
        if (accept('[')) {
            expression();
            expect(']');
        } else if (accept('(')) {
            if (accept(')')) {
            } else {
                argumentExpressionList();
                expect(')'); }
        } else if (accept('.')) {
```

⋮

```
        } else if (accept(Token::DEC_OP)) {
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `postfix_expression` always parses `primary_expression` first, so the first order of business is `primaryExpression()`.

Then, if the next character is any of the characters that follow the recursive `postfix_expression` in the remaining seven rules, then you are parsing the `postfix_expression`. Which gets you another `posfix_expression`, so you repeat again.

I won't write the C++ code for you, but in pseudocode:

```
postfixExpression()
{
    primaryExpression();
    while (next character is any of the characters that follow
           postfix_expression in the remaining seven rules)
    {
         parse_the_appropriate_rule();
    }
}
```